# Twig javascript path with id

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I normally use this peace of code.

```
<a href="{{ path('person_edit', {'id': 0}) }}' + document.getElementById('person_search').value;">
   Goto item 
</a>
```

Which will generate correct url for route `/edit/{id}`, but when I can change routes into `{id}/edit` I have to rewrite this code.(Not so effective.)

Is it some possibility to use `document.getElementById('person_search').value` inside an 'id'.

E.G. (doesn't work):

```
<a href="{{ path('person_edit', {'id': 'document.getElementById('person_search').value'}) }}">
   Goto item 
</a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible as the twig code gets interpreted and executed serverside e.g way before your javascript in your browser executes, what u can definetly do is use query parameters like :

```
path = '{{ path('person_edit', {'id': 0}) }}?userId='+document.getElementById("user_id").value;
```

in controller you do like

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$userId= $request->get("userId");
```

But this way your url will always be with id 0 so ommit it or build the url with javascript or use this bundles that does the job

[Fos Routing Js Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)